# Match two groups but none of them should be empty

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, regex-lookarounds

I want my regex to be able to match strings of random chars optionally followed by some digits - but if both matches are empty I want the match to fail. I am currently constructing the regex as in:

```
regex = u'^(.*)'
if has_digits: regex += u'(\d*)'
regex += ext + u'$' # extension group as in u'(\.exe)'
rePattern = re.compile(regex, re.I | re.U)
```

but this also matches empty filenames (with extension only). Can't wrap my head around similar questions like:

- [In a regular expression, match one thing or another, or both](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13351990/281545)
- [Matching a group that may or may not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6664015/281545)

The extra complication is that the second group (the digits) may not be added

So valid:

```
abc%.exe
123.exe
```

If has_digits is true:

```
abc 123.exe # I want the second group to contain the 123 not the first one
```

Invalid : `.exe`

Comment: Can't you replace `*` operators by `+` ?

Comment: @FedericoPiazza No because the digits may not exist even if has_digits is true - and if has_digits is true then the first group is optional _if_ there are some digits

Comment: Can you show some valid/invalid sample matches?

Comment: @Tim The groups are different depending on has_digits

Comment: @revo: doesn't this mean that it will match `.exe` ? That is doesn't the `?` make the first match optional ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex:

```
^(.*?)(\d+)?(?<=.)\.exe$
```

Positive lookbehind assures that there is at least one character before extension part.

**[Live demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/CNBQyG/1)**

Integrated:

```
regex = '^(.*?)'
if has_digits: regex += '(\d+)?'
regex += '(?<=.)' + ext + '$'
rePattern = re.compile(regex, re.I | re.U)
```

Comment: Thanks - what does the ? do in `(.*?)` ? Is it equivalent to `(.*)?` ? EDIT: followed your link - explains all :) Let me test this...

Comment: Still not quite sure the ? is needed - if I omit it it will eat up the digits ?

Comment: `(.*?)` differs from `(.*)?` in the sense that `.*?` is an un-greedy dot star quantifier (which can consume no character at all) but `(.*)?` is a greedy dot star quantifier that consumes characters as much as possible (the reason why digits are not captured by the second group). The latter is made optional by appending `?` to grouping construct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
ext = r'\.exe'

regex = r'^(?=.+\.)(.*?)'
if has_digits: regex += r'(\d*)'
regex += ext + '$'
rePattern = re.compile(regex, re.I | re.U)
# ^(?=.+\.)(.*?)(\d*)\.exe$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DXv0ep/1)

Lookahead `(?=.+\.)` ensures presence of at least one character before DOT.

Comment: Thanks - interesting variation - just @revo got there first :)

Comment: Yes, that also works. This is a bit faster due to lookahead and no optional group.

Comment: Haha thanks (it would be unfair to unaccept but I will probably use yours then :) Your using `r''` just made me realize that: _Unlike Standard C, all unrecognized escape sequences are left in the string unchanged, i.e., the backslash is left in the string_ -> https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals